# How to check whether Microsoft outlook is opened or not in c++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, outlook

I want to perform a specific action in my application based on whether outlook is opened or not.

I tried this piece of code, but it is always returning false.

```
CLSID clsid;
HRESULT hr = CLSIDFromProgID(_T("Outlook.Application"), &clsid);
if (hr != S_OK) 
return false;

IUnknown *pUnknown = NULL;
hr = GetActiveObject(clsid, 0, &pUnknown);
return (hr == S_OK);
```

Could anyone please let me know how do we check whether "Outlook" is opened or not in c++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Get the snapshot of all process running in the system, iterate to find
>   whether "outlook" is present in any of the exe name.

```
void isOutlookRunning()    
{           
    bool retval = false; 
    PROCESSENTRY32 t_entry;
    t_entry.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);
    HANDLE t_snapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, NULL);

    if (Process32First(t_snapshot, &t_entry))
    {
        while (Process32Next(t_snapshot, &t_entry))
        {   
            if(StrStrI(t_entry.szExeFile,"outlook")
                retval = true; 
        }
    }

    CloseHandle(t_snapshot); 
    return retval;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for solution and it works. If i see the code snippet added by you it consists of a hard coded string "outlook". Is that OK to check with hard coded value. Will it remain the same i.e,(OUTLOOK.EXE),if it remains the same there is no worry in checking the substring. Just a small doubt could you please clarify if you have any idea.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, C++ standard will not help in this case, as your question is operating system specific.

You can use "WinAPI" if you are on windows OS.

Below are some steps. The code for below steps is available in below MSDN link. You can modify the code as required for your usage.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682623(v=vs.85).aspx

1. Call "EnumProcesses". Will return the list of process IDs.
2. Iterate through each process using process ID return by "EnumProcesses".
3. Then find the name of process using "OpenProcess" and "GetModuleBaseName" as shown in above MSDN link.
4. Search for the string "Outlook" in the process name returned by above step (step 3).

This is a rough way I know.